# Specific css file style only apply to specific div

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, conflict

I'm using more than 2 css files in my asp.net MVC application so those files get conflicted with one another including `site.css` so i can't work properly with the style in my application. Actually I need to use a specific css file to the specific div in that application. Is there any way to use css file styles should apply to specific div.

**Note :** I have used the below code which i got in google.

```
<div id='container'>
<style scoped>
 @@import url.content('~/testFolder/test.css');
</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS applies to entire documents.

If you want to limit the scope, then you need to make use of a descendent selector.

e.g. #id_of_div .the .rest .of .the .selector {}

You have to apply this to every selector, and take into account groups (so it isn't as simple as just prefixing the whole stylesheet and suffixing every })

You would also find the stylesheet for the main document applying to your preview.

A frame would probably be the best approach to solving this problem.

Comment: I have tried this @soumya, but site.css and jquery.ui.css conflicting each other how can i modify their styles.?

Comment: the style which u need to override..please use "important" to override that style.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 0):

There is conflict between your defined css file  and  jquery imported cdn library css just imported library overriding your defined css file 
 segregate both css using id,class level selector

Answer (score 0):

```
There is conflict between your defined css file  and  jquery imported cdn library css just imported library overriding your defined css file 
 segregate both css using id,class level selector
#site {
    font-size: 14px;
  //preferred way
}

#div #site {
    font-size: 10px;
//  conflicting the font-size of div && overriding the size property
}
```